# Language and automata textbook, free or low cost?

Tags: soft-question, teaching, books

I'll be teaching a standard undergraduate class on languages and automata next semester, and would prefer to use a legitimate free or low-cost text. Any suggestions?

I love the Sipser text but the latest edition costs $196, which is hard to say with a straight face in the age of free courses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maheshwari and Smid's [Introduction to Theory of Computation](http://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/TheoryOfComputation/TheoryOfComputation.pdf) is free, with a Creative Commons license. It has some computability and complexity theory as well but seems to be primarily on languages and automata.

Comment: Thanks! I will probably use this as the main text, augmented with the Fleck & Har-Peled lecture notes.

Answer (score 8):

[Models of Computation — Exploring the Power of Computing](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~jes/book/pdfs/ModelsOfComputation.pdf) by John E. Savage *(Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivative Works 3.0 United States license)*.

Answer (score 6):

There are class notes online. For example...
http://valis.cs.uiuc.edu/~sariel/teach/notes/373/

Answer (score 2):

I totally recommend the draft of a book [Mathematical Foundations of Automata Theory](http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~jep/PDF/MPRI/MPRI.pdf) by [Jean-Eric Pin](http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~jep/indexAnglais.html). Also, you should check his home page for more automata related stuff. Note however that this books is oriented to semigroup-theory, so it depends on what you want to teach to your students.

Comment: That's hardly an introductory text.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a fine text, but my target audience doesn't generally have any abstract algebra background.