# Free books (or course materials) on undergraduate algorithms

Tags: ds.algorithms, books

What free books (or course materials) are there that cover undergraduate algorithms material?  I added "course materials" in case there exist comprehensive sets of lecture notes/video/other that are not quite organized in a book format but that are at least as effective as a book.

[A similar question about Language and Automata.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12800/language-and-automata-textbook-free-or-low-cost)

Comment: What about [Introduction to algorithms](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/index.htm) at MIT OpenCourseWare? It has 24 video lessons and 24 recitation videos (models of computation, sorts, binary search, AVL trees, ...) + problem sets and solutions

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I wonder why they say that CLRS is required though.

Comment: here is a meta-list; enjoy ;-)

https://github.com/prakhar1989/awesome-courses#algorithms

Comment: The notes by Jeff Erickson are well-known, and what I have read from them is excellent: http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/

Comment: Dasgupta, Papadimitriou, and Vazirani used to available on Umesh's website but the link doesn't work anymore. The chapters seem still accessible though.

Comment: ps: also check Tim's course on coursera.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems Princeton has a similar course.  But I can't access the material?

Comment: Coursera recently launched a specialization on basic algorithms: https://www.coursera.org/specializations/data-structures-algorithms. As far as I understand in the free version you see all the materials, but can't submit your solutions.

Comment: @EmanueleViola: the princeton one is this http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/ (unless there's several princeton ones)

Answer (score 4):

Jeff Erickson's lecture notes on [Algorithms](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/) are free, with a Creative Commons license. Other than Algorithms, this site also contains lecture notes for Models of Computation, which are also with a CC license.